# Pass functions with parameters as action

Tags: task, parameter-passing, action, timespan

I'm trying to pass function with parameters as action to RunInBackground() function. I was looking for the solution at stack overflow and another websides but coudn't find right solution for problem, i don't even know how to name, what i want do - correctly.

```
    async Task RunInBackground(TimeSpan timeSpan, Action action// as FUNCTION WITH PARAMETERS)
    {
        var periodicTimer = new PeriodicTimer(timeSpan);
        while (await periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            action();
        }
    }
    
    RunInBackground(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3), moveMonster(parametr1, parametr2)<-getting an error);
```

I'm getting also error - CS7036:There is no argument given that corresponds to re required formal parameter 'parameter2' of 'MoveMonster(int, int)'

```
void moveMonster(int parametr1, int parametr2)
{


    int monster1PositionY = parametr1;
    int monster1PositionX = parametr2;

    int movmentNumber = drawNumber(monster1);
    switch (movmentNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionY = monster1.moveRight(monster1PositionY);
            map.movefillRightMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionY = monster1.moveLeft(monster1PositionY);
            map.movefillLeftMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;

        case 3:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionX = monster1.moveDown(monster1PositionX);
            map.movefillDownMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;

        case 4:
            Console.Clear();
            monster1PositionX = monster1.moveUp(monster1PositionX);
            map.movefillUpMonster(monster1PositionX, monster1PositionY);
            map.printBoard();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to pass function with parameters to RunInBackground function like this:

```
RunInBackground(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
 {
     moveMonster(monster1); moveMonster(monster2); moveMonster(monster3);

 });
```